# Android app displays previous screen contents while displaying modal screen (React Native)

Tags: android, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app, react-native-navigation

I have a developed a small **hybrid** application using `react-native` technology.

I have made use of **react-native-navigation** for `navigation` purposes.

For **IOS** everything works fine but for android i am facing one issue.

I have a home screen and from which i am displaying a modal screen with the help of function `this.props.navigator.showModal`.

For android the new modal screen is displayed but it also displays the previous screen(home screen) contents underneath of it.

I don't understand why its happening and could not figure out the issue.

Comment: for best quality : 1 read how to ask question document in stackoverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask / 2 stop using **BOLD** every where / 3 stop using sentence like : `help me` `thanks` for `helping` and `etc` ... everybody knows you asked a question and can help you by answering

Answer (score 0):

In RNN v1, modals have transparent background and don't detach the screen displayed beneath them. This behaviour applies only to Android and was consolidated with iOS in v2.